# How to disable ad personalization as "boolean" using on iOS using GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_DEFAULT_ALLOW_AD_PERSONALIZATION_SIGNALS?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics

The documentation says:

> To set the default personalized advertising behavior, set the value of
> GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_DEFAULT_ALLOW_AD_PERSONALIZATION_SIGNALS to NO
> (Boolean) in your app's Info.plist file.

I am confused. `No` is not a boolean.

Should I set it like this:

```
<key>GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_DEFAULT_ALLOW_AD_PERSONALIZATION_SIGNALS</key>
<string>NO</string>
```

or

```
<key>GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_DEFAULT_ALLOW_AD_PERSONALIZATION_SIGNALS</key>
<false/>
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's your second code snippet. Place this in the first `<dict>` in your app's `Info.plist` file:

```
<key>GOOGLE_ANALYTICS_DEFAULT_ALLOW_AD_PERSONALIZATION_SIGNALS</key>
<false/>
```